# How to assign a static ip address before eth link running in ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, ethernet, dhcp

I know that if I need to assign a static ip address I will need to use `netplan` in Ubuntu 18.04, and I have done exactly that and made it work.

Here is my config file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: yes
    enp131s0f0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.66.0.1/24]
```

After I use `netplan apply`, the `ifconfig` command shows the ip address of `enp131s0f0` set to `10.66.0.1` **after I plug the cable into the port for "enp131s0f0"**. This causes a problem because if I do not plug in the cable to this port, the port itself won't get a static ip address even if the ipaddress is set in netplan, this will cause some services to fail to start (eg, isc-dhcp-server).

For example, if you have 3 ports and you have configured them like so:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp131s0f0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.66.0.1/24]
    enp131s0f1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.66.1.1/24]
    enp131s0f2:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.66.2.1/24]
    enp131s0f3:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.66.3.1/24]
```

If isc-dhcp-server is installed on all these 3 ports. The isc-dhcp-server will start only if you connect all 3 ports, if you failed to connect your cable to any one port of these 3 ports the isc-dhcp-server will fail to start because the port does not have a static address (without the cable plugged into the port), even if you set the static ip address in netplan.

So I would like to ask how to permanently assign a static address to a net port. To make it have an ipaddress before I plug in the cable... I need this because there are some ports on my server that currently I do not use (the cable is left unplugged), but I need isc-dhcp-server to start...

Comment: Are you using a **desktop** or **server** installation?

Comment: status please...

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal .yaml file for your configuration... this assumes that 10.66.0.2 is an available static address on your network, and that 10.66.0.1 is the proper gateway...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
    enp4s0f0:
      addresses: [10.66.0.2/24]
      gateway4: 10.66.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
      optional: true # may or may not be desired, to stop 2 minute boot delay
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply configuration

`reboot` # reboot and verify operation

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the OP's concerns that having network cables unplugged on various NICs is causing problems. Your config resembles the OP's very closely, is the lack of a gateway address and nameserver what's causing the issue when a cable is unplugged?

Comment: @Arronical the primary problem is that OP tried to assign a static IP using (probably) the IP of the gateway.

Comment: That's a good point! I missed that. They're trying to install a DHCP server so perhaps they're trying to create some sort of router? The second example shows different values in the 3rd octet so may be a possibility?

Comment: @Arronical same problem there... assigning the IP to the gateway address.