# How Assign Static IP using Netplan so isc-dhcp-server doesn't crash

Tags: 18.04, bash, ethernet, dhcp, netplan

I have a small router I am developing on Ubuntu 18.04 desktop and when I boot it without ethernet attached Netplan doesn't seem to assign the fixed IP (on the LAN side). WAN side is connected with DHCP. The LAN eth0 interface is what isc-dhcp-server runs on.

**Problem** : isc-dhcp-server crashes when it starts because no IP address exists on the eth0 interface.

If I do thinks manually with a device connected on eth0 then all works well. So the static IP is working when something is attached to eth0.

How do I get 192.168.10.1 assigned to eth0 (enp2s0 on this system) even if it's not plugged in?

I have a single .YAML file as follows:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.10.1/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 1.1.1.1
        search: []
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: yes
  version: 2
 renderer: NetworkManager
```

Alternately - is there an easy way to just launch (or restart) isc-dhcp-server based on a trigger of the interface getting connected?

This was a very similar question below but it wasn't closed or validated from the OP ... and I haven't successfully found a way to accomplish this. Any help is appreciated.

[Similar Question not Closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147147/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-before-eth-link-running-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

**Update 8/3/19**: As noted above w.r.t. restarting the server, I found that the cable state can be found reliably at /sys/class/net/enp2s0/carrier  -- the value in that file being 0 when disconnected and 1 when being connected.

So it seems then quite logical to have a script that would test this value - if the value is zero do nothing , if the value changes from 0 to 1 then execute a command , and finally if the value stays as 1 or changes from 1 to 0 do nothing. How would I write a bash script to accomplish this?

**Update 8/14/19**: Found a resolution following the answer below - but make sure you have ifupdown installed - my system did not. I did not pursue the script idea as the solution to get the static IP seems reliable.

Comment: Try adding `optional: true` to your eth0 stanza. Edit your question and show me your .yaml file. (And the question you link to, was answered, by me, but the original poster never showed up again.)

Comment: And... 192.168.10.1 may not be a good address choice, as it's possibly the same as the gateway address... similar problem in the other question.

Comment: `optional: true` is definitely the *opposite* of what you want in principle, because it means services should not wait for this interface to come up on boot before being started.

Comment: Agree @slangasek that 'optional: true' does not do what I want ; tried it for kicks but no change. The static IP is only assigned after I plug in a cable, but by that point the dhcp server has already exited with an error and stopped running.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for the tip, but there is no conflict with a local GW address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For networkd, try this .yaml file...**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses:
        - [192.168.10.1/24]
      gateway4: 
        - 192.168.xx.xx
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 1.1.1.1
        search: []
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: yes
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

**For NetworkManager, use this .yaml file...**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

and then edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to something similar to this...

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
        address 192.168.10.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.xx.xx
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
```

`reboot`

**Update #1:**

- decided to use NetworkManager
- installed `ifupdown`

Comment: Thanks @heynnema , I plan to use NetworkManager on this system but when using netplan why also configure /etc/network/interfaces ? I thought that is ignored. I don't even think ifup or ifdown are installed but when I'm back at machine on Mon I will gave a try.

Comment: @user9974748 report back on Mon, ok? For netplan, you don't use the /etc/network/interfaces file. But you mixed/matched stuff in your .yaml file. In desktop, if you leave /etc/network/interfaces with only the first two lines, you can use the GUI to do the same thing. Please remember to accept my answer if it turns out to be helpful, ok? Thanks!

Comment: I will definitely try on Mon @heynnema and will not to forget to mark answer if it solves problem ... but what is mixed in my YAML file? If the renderer is defined as NetworkManager and I define things in YAML I still don't understand the need for /etc/network/interfaces but I will experiment. Also pls remember that the interfaces and address all work when a cable is present - the issue is when no cable is present no IP is assigned to the interface card. It shows as "up" but doesn't have an IP.

Comment: @user9974748 I think the thing to watch for is, after editing /etc/network/interfaces, and the .yaml, it'll use ifupdown to manage the ethernet hardware. That by itself may make isc-dhcp-server behave itself. As you say... play with it a little and see what happens, but try my way first, ok? Check out https://netplan.io/examples for NetworkManager examples. Report back.

Comment: When I define interfaces in /etc/network/interfaces they don't show up at all. I put them back in YAML and they showed up again. Maybe it's stating the obvious, but to be clear they show up with ifconfig and also with NetworkManager GUI on the desktop so they seem defined correct, just the static one doesn't get an IP w/o a cable attached.

Comment: Normally, with NM, I tell folks to leave the first two lines of /etc/network/interfaces (the lo lines) and the rest empty, and use the NM GUI to define their static addresses. Set the .yaml as per my answer for NM, and edit down the interfaces file, reboot, set it up with the GUI, and you should be fine. Make sure to select the hardware device in the GUI, and then again for the second ethernet card. Then you can retest the static IP without the cable connected.

Comment: I tried your suggestion @heynnema - in interfaces file I just have the lo definition. In .YAML file just the couple line declaration and then configured the interfaces using GUI but behavior is same. All works until reboot w/o cable connected. Plug cable in -> get IP address , unplug cable -> IP address goes away

Comment: @user9974748 Sorry about that. One of these ways should have worked. Maybe there's something weird about the network cards or their driver. Do `sudo lshw -C network` and see if the driver is `r8169`. If so, we can try switching to `r8168-dkms` and see if that fixes it. Otherwise, I guess that I'm out of ideas.

Comment: It is indeed @heynnema - thanks for another idea to try - here is the portion from the listing that shows it:  driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms` and rebooted ; lshw indicated the 8168 driver was loaded instead. No difference :(   I don't understand if I have a HW or SW issue ... and with such a basic thing how does anyone build a router with 18.04 knowing DHCP will fail and stop if a cable isn't connected?

Comment: @user9974748 last ditch suggestion... try 19.04 and see what happens. Report back.

Comment: I just brought up a brand new UP Extreme board with 2 different NICs on it with igb driver. Ubuntu 19.04 fresh install. Same situation! Seems something inherent with the network handling static IPs in ubuntu now ... no cable detect -> no IP address. < insert banging head against wall sound here>  .   How to make a router??

Comment: @user9974748 well... you've certainly done due diligence in trying to get this thing going. I'm out of good ideas now. Please do let me know if you ever figure this out. Cheers friend!

Comment: I think I have something working now @heynnema ! I used your suggestion to have only 3 lines in netplan .yaml, then defined static interface in /etc/network/interfaces and then installed ifupdown - with my 18.04 and 19.04 installs that was missing. Now I have an IP address with or without the cable present, however I didn't configure anything with NM GUI. If this seems logical maybe update your answer and it would be complete. Thx for the inspiration and getting me on the right track!

Comment: @user9974748 Great news! It looks like my original answer is what worked, except you didn't use the NM GUI... but it works! Answer updated. Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!